# printing member string of a structure in a vector to cout stream

Tags: c++, vector

what is the best way to print a member string of structure stored in vector , I tried to get the string using `const_iterator` of the vector, but the result is only the initial values made by class constructor (empty strings) . Thanks in advance

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>

class X
{

public:
    std::string s1 , s2, s3 ;
    X()
    {
        s1 = " " ;
        s2 = " " ;
        s3 = " " ;
    }

};

void getstring(const char* msg , std::string storage)
{
    std::cout << msg ;
    std::getline(std::cin,storage) ;

}

int main()
{
    std::vector<X>data ;
    std::vector<X>::const_iterator it ;

    int register_no ;
    std::cout << "Enter Registers No. : " ;
    std::cin>>register_no;

    X temp ;

    for (int i = 0 ; i < register_no ; i++)
    {

        getchar();

        getstring("Enter s1 : " , temp.s1);
        getstring("Enter s2 : " , temp.s2) ;
        getstring("Enter s3 : " , temp.s3) ;

        data.push_back(temp) ;
    }

    for (it=data.begin() ; it != data.end(); ++it)
    {
        //following code is not effective:
        std::cout << (*it).s1 << std::endl ;
        std::cout << (*it).s2 << std::endl ;
        std::cout << (*it).s3 << std::endl ;
    }

}
```

Comment: You need to pass the second parameter by reference in `getstring`, ie `std::string &storage`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this modification:

```
void getstring(const char* msg , std::string& storage)
{
    std::cout << msg ;
    std::getline(std::cin,storage) ;

}
```

Note: making the string parameter a reference in order to copy to the member. If parameters are not declared as references, then the parameter is passed "by value" meaning the parameter is copied into the interior of the function, and when the function returns the parameter is erased.

Answer (score 0):

You passing the string by value for this the read value is storage in the local variable string of method getstring.

void getstring(const char* msg , **std::string&** storage)

Should recommend also change `(*it).s1` for `it->s1`.

Comment: What's the rerasoning behind your preference of `it->s1` over `(*it).s1`?

Comment: cleaner syntax, avoid parenthesis (in the example is really simple and probably unimportant but while chaining two or three nested iterator access, the parenthesis count begin to grow to the point that it's difficult known to what expression belong